# Enable or Disable WebGl

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I would like to know if we can enable or disable WebGL manually in LightningChart JS. The question is because I don´t know if the library is actually printing series with WebGL or isn´t.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to disable WebGL in the LightningChart JS library itself. It requires WebGL to work properly.

It is possible to disable WebGL from Chrome with `--disable-3d-apis` command line switch. ([source](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-3d-apis))
When launching chrome with that switch, make sure to close all other chrome instances as otherwise the command line switch will not take effect.

To disable WebGL in Firefox, open `about:config` page and search for `webgl.disabled` and set that flag to `true`.

When the 3D api's are disabled, LightningChart JS will fail to render and will throw an error.